# Does Lean have a function that reads a file "at compile time"?

Tags: lean, lean4

Is there some "pure" function that reads a file before the program is type-checked and returns its contents as a string or something, for example if the file `file.txt` has the contents `hello` then I could write

```
example : readFile "file.txt" = "hello" := rfl
```

The reason I am asking is because I would like to implement a domain-specific language that compiles to a proof of something in Lean. For example if the file has a proof then I could write

```
example : 2 + 2 = 4 := interpretProof (readFile "file.txt")
/- or -/
theorem p : thingProvedBy (readFile "file.txt") := interpretProof (readFile "file.txt")
#check p -- p : 2 + 2 = 4
```

The alternatives that I can think of would be to (a) compile the DSL into Lean code and import it or (b) implement the DSL using the Lean macro system so that it can be written directly in a Lean program.

Comment: IO is never “pure”.  Nonetheless, you can use meta programming to achieve at least some of your goal.  In Lean 3 you can either write a tactic which reads from a file or make a custom user command.  In Lean 4 I’m sure there are also similar options, likely involving macros or custom tactics.

Comment: I or someone else might be able to tell you exactly how to achieve your goal but it will be different for lean 3 or lean 4.  Can you edit your question to be clear on which one your are interested in?

Comment: Tag (and mention of the macro system, which personally would be my favorite solution, naturally) suggest Lean 4. In that case, see https://github.com/leanprover/doc-gen4/blob/5b56be76f2e0e0a4e3a74bc66410cc9cbb17e159/DocGen4/Output/Base.lean#L107-L118 (impl: https://github.com/leanprover/doc-gen4/blob/main/DocGen4/IncludeStr.lean) for such a term elaborator. Having said that, if you go this course, you might want to make `interpretProof` part of the metaprogram as well for performance.

Comment: Why do you want DSL proofs to be in separate files? That sounds very annoying for anyone who will have to write these.

Comment: Because they may use syntax that isn't supported by Lean's macro system. Having them in separate files would also enable one to implement syntax highlighting for the DSL.

Comment: Ok, although Lean's syntax is pretty accommodating, and the burden of having to store stuff in separate files is very likely not worth it. At least store it in strings (or *also* allow storage in string).

Comment: @mrsnuggles Supporting semantic highlighting for custom eDSLs is definitely within the realms of possibility for the Lean language server

Comment: did you find a good answer for this question ?